# Call function when going back to previous component in React-Native

Tags: react-native

I have a component that locks the screen to landscape before rendering.

When I click on the `next button`, I go to the next screen which unlocks the orientation.

When I click on the `previous button`, I go back to the first screen.
(The navigation is done by `this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenName')` from `react-native-navigation`).

The screen now gets locked in the `componentDidMount` method, is there a similar method that gets called when you go back to an already rendered component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can do this in react-native-navigation is to pass parameters backwards. When you navigate back to your component pass a parameter that indicates that it went back. After that in your file where you want to have the function, have it listening for the wentBack prop.
Navigating backwards with a parameter:
`this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenName', {
              wentBack: true,
            });`

Listening for the parameter:

```
const { navigation } = this.props,
wentBack = navigation.getParam('wentBack', 'whatever default value - should be false');
```

Then in your render method you can render conditionally for whatever you want to show:

```
render() {
  return (
    <View>
    {wentBack ? 'do something it went back!' : 'it didn't go back'}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: In which function { navigation } = this.props, should put ?

Comment: Whichever component you're passing navigation to.

Comment: I am asking for lifecycle function , because constructor is not calling again nor didMount